# How to intercept view rendering to add HTML/JS on all partial views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to write the contents of a js file from a convention-driven location (like ~/ClientApp/Controllers/Home/Home.js if loading the view located at ~/Views/Home/Home.cshtml). How do I do this?

Example: if the file ~/Views/Home/Home.cshtml looks like:

```
<div id="some-partial-view">
   <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

And the file ~/ClientApp/Controllers/Home/Home.Controller.js looks like

```
function HomeController() {
  //some code
}
```

Then the rendered view returned by the webserver should look like (if using fiddler)

```
<!--ommitted <html> <body> tags -->

<div id="some-partial-view">
   <!-- ... -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function HomeController() {
       //some code
   }
</script>
```

One way is to add an HTML Helper that will do this such as:

```
<div id="some-partial-view" ng:Controller="HomeController">
   <!-- ... -->
</div>
@Html.IncludeController("HomeController")
```

However, i don't want to repeat this in all partial views.

Any ideas?

Comment: in your partial view reference your javascript file, <script type="text/javascript" src="/ClientApp/Controllers/Home/Home.Controller.js"></script>

Comment: I want to skip this step, hence the question. Want to weave the js file during view rendering. Also want to reduce the roundtrips, therefore this is not an option.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "weave the js file during view rendering"?

Comment: Have updated the question for clarity :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could write a custom view:

```
public class MyRazorView : RazorView
{
    public MyRazorView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string layoutPath, bool runViewStartPages, IEnumerable<string> viewStartFileExtensions, IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator)
        : base(controllerContext, viewPath, layoutPath, runViewStartPages, viewStartFileExtensions, viewPageActivator)
    {

    }

    protected override void RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, object instance)
    {
        base.RenderView(viewContext, writer, instance);

        var view = (BuildManagerCompiledView)viewContext.View;
        var context = viewContext.HttpContext;
        var path = context.Server.MapPath(view.ViewPath);
        var viewName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
        var controller = viewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var js = context.Server.MapPath(
            string.Format(
                "~/ClientApp/Controllers/{0}/{0}.{1}.js",
                viewName,
                controller
            )
        );
        if (File.Exists(js))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(
                string.Format(
                    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">{0}</script>",
                    File.ReadAllText(js)
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

and a custom view engine which will return this custom view when a partial view is to be requested:

```
public class MyRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        return new MyRazorView(
            controllerContext, 
            partialPath, 
            null, 
            false, 
            base.FileExtensions, 
            base.ViewPageActivator
        );
    }
}
```

which would be registered in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyRazorViewEngine());
}
```

You probably might need to adjust some of the paths as it was not quite clear in your question where exactly should the js be located but normally you should have enough details in the answer.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for :) Just thought there's another way than writing a custom view engine. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @leypascua, there are other ways but this one is the DRYiest.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov is there a way i could replace all the HTML from writer with something else ? Also, how could i execute this only when it's the view used by the controller action, for example i have a `HomeController` and action `Home` and i want this code to be executed only on the View `Home`. Today it's running from all of the views used on the page.

Answer (score 0):

it would make more sense to include all you javascript in the outter ring, then include that via index.php or wherever...

Personally I use jQuery and I include each object like so...

```
//View Objects
(function($){

var views = {

   init: function()
   {
      this.view1();
      this.view2();
   },
   view1 : function()
   {
     // I am
   },
   view2 : function()
   {
     // all yours
   }

}
//call/invoke my view objects
$(function(){

    //call view object via init()
    view.init();
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Not an option. The goal is to load JS on-demand, only when it is really needed.

Comment: if ( getElementbyID(id) ){ //load me ie: elements.sexyID();  }